# Есть ли в css псевдокласс аналог события - onmouseout ?

Tags: css

Есть ли в css псевдокласс, который является аналогом события mouseout ?

```
 .wall_album:hover  #wall{
    margin-top: 150px;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    }
```

Проблема в том, что при дефолтном состоянии, оно сбрасывает margin-top слишком быстро

А все я понял, надо было просто поставить в дефолт #wall transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если css решение, то я думаю тут нету смысла и понятия анховера , надо что-то типа  
     a { color:#aaa; } 
     a:hover { 
        color: #bbb; 
        font-style:bold; 
     }

Comment: то есть есть дефаултное значение и на ховер. Дефаултное и будет Вашим псевдоклассом

Answer (score 0):

Дэфолтное состояние и есть аналог mouseout. Задаешь стили для этого состояния. А для :hover стили для события mousein/mouseover